# Acessing Angular NgForOfContext in a directive

Tags: angular, user-interface, user-experience, ngfor, inplace-editing

I'm developing an Angular directive to detect (and delete) an empty item in an `*ngFor` list.

Instead of adding an `X` button (per item) that will trigger deletion, I'm more for a content based approach: if the user erases -- either completely or just some key fields of -- an item, it will cease to exist as soon as the user focuses on another part of the document.

[I've managed to make it](https://plnkr.co/edit/dUkJjLzMtkx9C0kUoomS) (and to my surprise it was not difficult at all). I'll highlight the key aspects here:

**Using the directive**

*template*

```
  <div *ngFor="let item of data; index as i"
    [appInPlaceDelete]="isEmpty"
    (delete)="onDelete(i)"
  >
```

*component*

```
  onDelete(i: number) {
    // code to erase ith item
  }

  private isEmpty(item): boolean {
    // logic to answer if item is empty or not
  }
```

**Implementation**

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appInPlaceDelete]'
})
export class InPlaceDeleteDirective<T> implements OnInit, DoCheck {
  @Input() appInPlaceDelete: (t: T) => boolean;
  @Output() delete: EventEmitter<undefined> = new EventEmitter();

  // ...

  private $implicit: T;
  private focusstream = new Subject<string>();

  constructor(private containerRef: ViewContainerRef) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    const context: NgForOfContext<T> = this.containerRef['_view'].context;
    this.$implicit = context.$implicit

    // code forwarding 'focusstream' to 'delete' output
  }

  // code that gives visual indication that the item will be deleted

  // ...
  // a bunch of @HostListeners feeding the focusstream
  // ...
}
```

Now, I'm pretty much satisfied with what I did, **except** for that one line:

```
    const context: NgForOfContext<T> = this.containerRef['_view'].context;
```

because acessing the `_view` property is not platform portable (perhaps this property only exists in `platformBrowserDynamic`).

**Here come the questions:**

1. **Is there any way to capture the `context` platform-independent-wise?**

`NgForOf` stuffs this context there platform independently, [as seen on its source code](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/af4eb00c9191f3eedfbb2b0bc6c471cd55f892a6/packages/common/src/directives/ng_for_of.ts#L160). Maybe there is (or should be) a way to retrieve that context portably. I know, the developer (me) still has the responsibility of knowing what does that context holds (its type). Hang on, that's for the next question.

2. **Can I make my `selector` more restrictive to hook only inside an `*ngFor` host?**

For this one I know we should bear in mind that angular translates the original template to:

```
<ng-template ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="data" let-i="index">
  <div
    [appInPlaceDelete]="isEmpty"
    (delete)="onDelete(i)"
  >
</ng-template>
```

So the actual `divs` the directive is hooking into are embedded views created dynamically by `NgForOf` directive.

I wonder if there is some way to enforce this (I tried `selector: '[ngFor] > [appInPlaceDelete]'` to no avail).

3. **Is there a workaround?**

The `delete` output clearly uses the context variable `i` (the directive itself knows nothing about `i`; it just issues an event through the `delete` channel).

I tried `[appInPlaceDelete]="isEmpty(item)"` though I knew in advance that it would bind `false` to `appInPlaceDelete`.

I also tried `[appInPlaceDelete]="() => isEmpty(item)"` and `...="function() { return isEmpty(item); }"` expecting that angular would create a closure grabbing `item` (and `isEmpty`) and pass that closure along. Also no success.

Though somewhat ugly, that would be better than a non-portable directive.

4. **Iff there is no other way to answer positively the 1st question, and also no workaround in the 3rd, how can I cover at least the most common platforms?**

Though not advisable, perhaps I could have some way to determine in which platform my directive is running under and access the `context` specifically.

In this matter I have to confess I have no clue about how to use (even less debug) anything else other than `platformBrowserDynamic`.

5. **If you've come so far, is there any other completely different way of doing it?**

The first 2 paragraphs in this post delineate what I'm trying to accomplish here. Everything else is just my solution (and the problems it entails).

Maybe there is a completely different way of doing it. Maybe someone already did/packed/published a better solution.

Comment: Consider to limit this to one question...

Comment: I don't understand how does it got flagged as "too broad"... sure it's a lengthy post, but just because I did my homework. It has 5 questions, but looking closely they are all tied together to the main point (grabbing the ngFor context without breaking platform independentness); the fact that I decided to unfold it in 5 (researched and commented) questions should be praised not lambasted.